# Android SQLite - drop table after failed transaction during upgrade

Tags: android, sqlite

The drop table is not doing anything after a failed transaction during an SQLite upgrade. The drop SQL doesn't throw an exception.

The only way I can get this to work is remove everything to do with transactions, but I want the database to be unchanged to analyse what went wrong during the upgrade.

```
private void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
  try {
      db.beginTransaction();
      // Exception occurs here
      db.setTransactionSuccessful();
      db.endTransaction();
  }catch(Exception e){
      db.endTransaction(); // Transaction is unsuccessful and changes rolled back
      // Save for analyses
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE ..."); // Drop table does nothing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onUpgrade` is already in a transaction block. To make this work how I want it to (although it ends a transaction it didn't start):

```
// Path to db on local storage
private String mDbToUpload = null;

@Override
private void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
  try {
      // Exception occurs here
  }catch(Exception e){
      db.endTransaction(); // End transaction to rollback changes
      mDbToUpload = ...// Save db to local storage
  }
}

@Override
private void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
  if(mDbToUpload != null){
    ... // Upload db from path
    mDbToUpload = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` lifecycle methods such as `onUpgrade()` are executed in a transaction. sqlite does not support nested transactions, and Android's `SQLiteDatabase` only emulates nested transactions with reference counting but such emulated nested transaction is not in fact a real transaction.

If you have a problem in a lifecycle method, throw an exception and the framework will roll back the outermost, actual transaction for you.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, int, int)

Do you know of anyway to run a particular piece code after the upgrade failed?

Comment: You can catch and rethrow exceptions on `onUpgrade()`

Comment: That would mean catching the exception wherever `getWriteableDatabase` is called, right?

Comment: That's another option and it might be harder to distinguish from problems in e.g. `onCreate()`. Anyway `onXxx()` needs to throw an exception if there's a problem but that does not prevent you from doing `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { /* something */ throw e; }`

Comment: Don't end transactions you did not start.

Comment: Unless there's a better way this is what I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Drop table query is executing after you call endtransaction. Check that order. That might be the reason.

Comment: I need it to execute after end transaction so that the changes from the transaction are rolled back.

Comment: endtransaction will do the rollback duty. Right?

Comment: why it matters to rollback the changes when u eventually droping the complete table

Comment: My post made it clear that I want to save the database for analyse before dropping the table.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of code is between beingTransaction and endTransaction, if it is `execSQL()`, you need to catch exception `SQLException`, if you are using insert, use `insertOrThrow()`, please don't expect `Exception e` will catch all exception..

Comment: This is just example code. It doesn't matter what exception is throw just that the transaction is rolled back and the table dropped. Either way this would make no different as SQLException is derived from Exception, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html